# Ti.media.showCamera throws 'undefined' error on iPhone but works fine on Android

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I am building an application for iOS and Android using Appaccelerator. It works perfectly fine on Android, but throws 'undefined' error every time I try to open it on iOS devices. The weird thing is, it doesnt show a proper error message.

First I thought it is a build issue, so I cleaned the project, and then rebuilt it, but it was not the case. I also manually deleted the build folder, and rebuild, but still no improvement.

Here is the code :

```
Rf.media.photo = {


key: 'photo',
  title: 'Photo',
  extension: 'jpg',
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  create: function(created) {

Ti.media.showCamera({
  animated: false,
  saveToPhotoGallery: false,
  showControls: true,
  success: function() { 

var name = Rf.util.timestamp() + '.' + Rf.media.photo.extension;
Rf.write_to_new_file(name, media_item.media, function(file) {
created(file);



 });
      },
      error:function(error)
        {
        // create alert
        var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'Camera'});

        // set message
        if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA)
        {
            a.setMessage('Please run this test on device');
        }
        else
        {
            a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
        }

        // show alert
        a.show();
    },
    cancel:function()
    {

    },
});


 }
};
```

I get this error message when people clikc on the "Photo" button.

```
[WARN] Exception in event callback. {
line = 1;
message = "'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Ti.Media.showCamera')";
name = TypeError;
sourceId = 52935904;
sourceURL = "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/F8398B04-78C4-4A45-BEE0-30EE4BFEBB00/App.app/photo.js";
```

Is there a way to "initialize" the Ti.Media.showCamera(); method, so it would not find itself 'undefined'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ti.media.showCamera({...` should be `Ti.Media.showCamera({...`

Also, in the success callback, there are no arguments to receive the returned media data.  You have `media_item.media` in your `write_to_new_file()` function, so your success callback should probably read: `success: function(media_item) {...`